# Error en herencia de Clase

Tags: java, netbeans, jcreator

A partir de la clase "**impresora**", definí una subclase llamada "**impTinta**", que herede la clase impresora. Para esta nueva clase, tenia que definir datos para almacenar niveles de tinta negra (*int Nivel_negro=100;*) y colores (*int Nivel_color=100;*), a la vez de añadir un método imprimir() que pueda configurarse para imprimir con tinta a color(1) o solo con tinta negra(0), dando como resultado una disminución de 10 unidades de cualquiera de las dos tintas (mediante el ingreso de teclado y escáner se define el 0 y 1 respectivamente). Pero no pasa así, al compilarlo siempre reconoce el valor escaneado en la variable "a" como 0 pero no 1 que hace referencia a impresión por colores. Por favor me podrían decir porque pasa esto

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class impresora {

   String marca;
   boolean estado=false;
    void encender(){
    boolean estado=true;
        System.out.println("Impresora encendida...");
        }
    void apagar(){
    boolean estado=false;
    System.out.println("Impresora apagada...");
        }
    void imprimir_prueba(){
            System.out.println("Imprimiendo página de prueba...\nMarca:"+marca);
        }
}

class impTinta extends impresora{
    int Nivel_negro=100;
    int Nivel_color=100;
    int a;


            void imprimir(){
                this.imprimir_prueba();
                if (a==0){
        Nivel_negro-=10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta negra:"+Nivel_negro);
        System.exit(0);
                }if (a==1){
        Nivel_color-=10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta color:"+Nivel_color);
        System.exit(0);     
                }if(a!=0 && a!=1){
        System.out.println("Error"); 
        System.exit(0); 

    }
   }
  }


class impreso{

    public impreso() {
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Seleccione 0 para B/N o 1 para color: ");
        a = myScanner.nextInt();


        impTinta imp1=new impTinta();
        imp1.marca="HP";
        if(imp1.estado==false)imp1.encender();
        imp1.imprimir();
        imp1.apagar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me gustaría hacer algunas observaciones.

En tu diseño se pueden identificar dos objetos: `Impresora` y `Cartucho`.

Entre esos dos no hay una relación de herencia ya que un cartucho no es un tipo de impresora. Si ves esos objetos en el mundo real puedes ver que una impresora tiene un cartucho. Así que un objeto de tipo `Impresora` debe tener adentro un objeto de tipo `Cartucho`.

Veamos la clase `Cartucho`:

```
class Cartucho {

    private int nivelNegro = 100;
    private int nivelColor = 100;

    public void imprimirNegro() {
        nivelNegro -= 10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta negra:" + nivelNegro);
    }

    public void imprimirColor() {
        nivelColor -= 10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta color:" + nivelColor);
    }

}
```

Tiene dos propiedades `nivelNegro` y `nivelColor`; y dos métodos para los dos modos de impresión que puede hacer.

Veamos la clase `Impresora`:

```
class Impresora {

    private String marca;
    private boolean estaEncendida;

    private Cartucho cartucho = new Cartucho();

    void encender() {
        estaEncendida = true;
        System.out.println("Impresora encendida...");
    }

    void apagar() {
        estaEncendida = false;
        System.out.println("Impresora apagada...");
    }

    void imprimirPrueba() {
        System.out.println("Imprimiendo página de prueba...\nMarca:" + marca);
        cartucho.imprimirColor();
        cartucho.imprimirNegro();
    }

    void imprimirNegro() {
        cartucho.imprimirNegro();
    }

    void imprimirColor() {
        cartucho.imprimirColor();
    }

    public boolean estaEncendida() {
        return estaEncendida;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}
```

Impresora tiene internamente un objeto de tipo `Cartucho` y todos los métodos relacionados con una impresora: `imprimirColor`, `imprimirNegro`, `encender`, `apagar`, `estaEncendida`. Como en el mundo real, los métodos de la clase representan la interfaz de esta con la que un usuario se comunica, en ningún momento el usuario se comunica con el cartucho.

Por ejemplo cuando un usuario quiere imprimir en negro:

```
void imprimirNegro() {
        cartucho.imprimirNegro();
    }
```

Es la impresora quien recibe la orden y la impresora ordena al cartucho que realice una impresión. Y todas las operaciones desde la creación, colocar la marca, comprobar si está encendida y más ocurren en el objeto impresora:

```
Impresora impresora = new Impresora();
impresora.setMarca("HP");

if (!impresora.estaEncendida()) impresora.encender();

impresora.imprimirPrueba();
```

Agrego el código completo con las observaciones,ediciones de estilo y por supuesto el error por el cual preguntas corregido:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Impresora {

    private String marca;
    private boolean estaEncendida;

    private Cartucho cartucho = new Cartucho();

    void encender() {
        estaEncendida = true;
        System.out.println("Impresora encendida...");
    }

    void apagar() {
        estaEncendida = false;
        System.out.println("Impresora apagada...");
    }

    void imprimirPrueba() {
        System.out.println("Imprimiendo página de prueba...\nMarca:" + marca);
        cartucho.imprimirColor();
        cartucho.imprimirNegro();
    }

    void imprimirNegro() {
        cartucho.imprimirNegro();
    }

    void imprimirColor() {
        cartucho.imprimirColor();
    }

    public boolean estaEncendida() {
        return estaEncendida;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}

class Cartucho {

    private int nivelNegro = 100;
    private int nivelColor = 100;

    public void imprimirNegro() {
        nivelNegro -= 10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta negra:" + nivelNegro);
    }

    public void imprimirColor() {
        nivelColor -= 10;
        System.out.println("Nivel de tinta color:" + nivelColor);
    }

}

public class Imprenta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Seleccione 0 para B/N o 1 para color: ");

        int eleccion = myScanner.nextInt();

        Impresora impresora = new Impresora();
        impresora.setMarca("HP");

        if (!impresora.estaEncendida()) impresora.encender();

        impresora.imprimirPrueba();

        if (eleccion == 1) {
            impresora.imprimirColor();
        } else if (eleccion == 0) {
            impresora.imprimirNegro();
        } else System.out.println("error");
        impresora.apagar();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo, agradezco su eficaz asistencia. He probado con su código y veo que cumplió con el objetivo aunque con el detalle de que la impresión por pantalla al seleccionar `1` para color, da como resultado una impresión `Nivel de tinta negra` pero dos `Nivel de tinta color`, uno con el valor operado `80` y otro sin operar `90`. Y al seleccionar `0` para b/n, da como resultado una impresión `Nivel de tinta color` pero dos `Nivel de tinta negra`, uno operado `80` y otro sin operar `90`. Omitiendo aquellos detalles, su código esta muy bien y me ha sido de gran ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Sí, eso es porque primero se llama a `imprimirPrueba()`. Si se quita eso ya solo imprimirá negro o color según la elección.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre es `0` porque ese es el valor inicial de cualquier `int` que no ha sido inicializada. Nunca es `1` porque el valor que retorna `myScanner.nextInt()` nunca es asignado a `imp1.a` sino que es asignado a otra variable del mismo nombre pero en la clase `impreso` cuyo alcance (scope) no es el mismo que `imp1.a`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda.